# Dequeue class printing address instead of QueueNode item

Tags: java, tostring, deque

I'm trying to create a Linked List dequeue class that accepts nodes at the head as well as rear. My method, tailRemove() should remove only the item at the tail of the deque. However, when I print it, it's printing the address. The toString() method works fine for all the other methods, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks for your help!

```
public class LinkedDequeue 
{
   private QueueNode front;      //index of current front element
   private QueueNode rear;       //index of current rear element
   private int count;            //current # of elements

   class QueueNode 
   {
      private Object data;
      private QueueNode link;
   }

   public LinkedDequeue ()
   {
      front = new QueueNode();
      rear = new QueueNode();
      count = 0;      
   } 

   public void headAdd (Object o)
   {
      QueueNode temp = new QueueNode();
      temp.data = o;

      if (isEmpty()) 
      {
         front = temp;
         rear = front;
         front.link = null;
         rear.link = null;
      }
      else
      {
         temp.link = front;
         front = temp;
      }

      count++;
   }

   public void tailAdd (Object o)
   {
      QueueNode temp = new QueueNode();
      temp.data = o;
      temp.link = null;

      if (front == null) front = rear = temp;
      else 
      {
         rear.link = temp;
         rear = temp;
      }   
      count++;
   }

   public Object tailPeek()
   {
      return rear.data;
   }

   public Object tailRemove()
   {
      QueueNode temp = new QueueNode ();
      QueueNode end = new QueueNode();
      if (isEmpty()) return null;
      else
      {
         temp = front;

         while (temp.link != rear)
         {
            temp = temp.link;
         }

         end = rear;
         rear.data = temp.data;
         rear.link = null;
         count--;

         return end;
      } 
   }

   public String toString()
   {
      QueueNode current = front;
      StringBuilder elements = new StringBuilder();

      while (current != null)
      {
         elements.append (current.data + "\n");
         current = current.link;      
      }

      return elements.toString();
   }



   public static void main (String [] args)
   {
      LinkedDequeue list = new LinkedDequeue ();

      list.headAdd ("test?");
      list.tailAdd("in the middle perhaps");
      list.tailAdd ("yikes, does this work?");

      System.out.println (list.toString());

      System.out.println (list.tailPeek());
      System.out.println (list.tailRemove());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `tailRemove()` returns back an Object of type `QueueNode`. So when you pass it to `System.out.println()` it invokes the `toString()` method of `QueueNode` class. Since you haven't provided a custom implementation of `toString()` in your `QueueNode` class it calls the default implementation in `Object` class and prints the hashCode of the Object.

**Solution :** 
You need to override toString() method in your QueueNode class as well.

Comment: OP's question was regarding System.out.println (list.tailRemove());...in this the OP is returning the QueueNOde object, hence overriding toString() for QueueNode will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

As [Kakarot mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23636361/2030691), creating a `toString()` method in the `QueueNode` class will solve the problem.  Your `end` variable, which is what you are printing, doesn't have a custom `toString()` method.

The reason is that in Java, the default `toString()` method every object has only prints its memory address.  If you want it to do something useful, you need to override it yourself.